# analysis of core dump frame using gdb

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

I am analysing a core dump generated by my application. From the stack trace I can see the below lines
    #0  0x00779eff in raise () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6

```
#1  0x0077b705 in abort () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6

#2  0x006554f7 in __cxa_call_unexpected () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5

#3  0x00655544 in std::terminate () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5

#4  0x006556b6 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5

#5  0x006558d2 in operator new () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5


#6  0x006559bf in operator new[] () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5
#7  0x090c15df in Buffer::resize ()

#8  0x090bd230 in Buffer::Buffer ()
```

The definition of Buffer function is as follows

```
int
Buffer::resize (
    size_t      size    
    )
{
    …….
}
```

Now I have selected frame 7

```
    (gdb) f 7
#7  0x090c15df in Buffer::resize ()
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 7, frame at 0xbfff82f0:
 eip = 0x90c15df in Buffer::resize(unsigned int); saved eip 0x90bd230
 called by frame at 0xbfff8310, caller of frame at 0xbfff8280
 Arglist at 0xbfff82e8, args: 
 Locals at 0xbfff82e8, Previous frame's sp is 0xbfff82f0
 Saved registers:
  ebx at 0xbfff82e4, ebp at 0xbfff82e8, esi at 0xbfff8250, edi at 0xbfff8254, eip at 0xbfff82ec
```

But wanted to check what is the value of size passed to it
How do I do that ? Any help will be appreciated

Thanks
SKP

Comment: This depends a bit on whether your code is compiled with debug symbols or not. Since the resize function is called from the constructor, can't you check what value the parameter is that is used from this, or is the size given to the constructor as a parameter as well?

Comment: Yah it is compiled with -g option

Comment: Are you trying to debug optimized code?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way (adjusted since question changed):

```
p size
```

`p` (short for print) will emit value of `size`.

Pro-tip: Hit `Ctrl`+`x`+`a` to see the code you are currently executing. (Could also got with `list` `gdb`-command.)

Comment: Not able to print in this way

Comment: What do you see? You made sure to compile with `-g` (ie. with dbg symbols), correct?

Comment: If I give list it shows as (gdb) list 
1 in <<C++-namespaces>>

Comment: @user3160866 why are you not able to print that way? do you not have access to the print (p) command in GDB?